# VPN server IP address

Tags: vpn, ip

If I use VPN service when I get fix ip address or it's dynamic?

Secondly, can I change the fix VPN ip or it's impossible?

I want to change my ip every second.

Thanks!

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341). Whatever your outer problem is, changing your IP frequently is not the way to solve it.

Comment: Can you give me example for Dynamic IP VPN Provider?

Comment: We can't help you solve a problem if we don't know what the problem is.

Comment: I looking for free dynamic ip VPN provider

Comment: What @DavidSchwartz means, is that you would need to state your actual need. In other words, "**why** do you need a free dynamic ip VPN provider?". Because the very fact of changing ip that fast is not practical, and not really going to work ideally with the way most of the Internet works.

Comment: To compare, it's like asking: "I need to know how to build a house which can rotate itself during the day, please advise", when the actual problem is that the sun on your LCD screen prevents you from reading on it during the afternoon.

Answer (score 2):

> If I use VPN service when I get fix ip address or it's dynamic?

Depends how the VPN server is set up, usually there is a dynamic pool unless the administrator assigns static IPs.

> Secondly, can I change the fix VPN ip or it's impossible?

It is possible, but, I wouldn't recommend it - like on any network connection, simply type the IP you want - it must be within a range that is routable by the server.

> I want to change my ip every second.

Seriously?... It will take on average half a second to connect to a VPN, this is just silly...

Comment: Can you give me any advice?